# French Fanfiction

Tags: culture

I was just wondering, are there French fan fiction communities? Like an FF.Net specific to French? For an example we have from Germany, https://www.fanfiktion.de/ Anything like that, but for French speakers?

Thanks! (:

Answer (score 1):

A simple search on the net gives:

https://www.fanfictions.fr/